# How to share title, image and post in Facebook?

Tags: php, facebook

I am sharing title, image and description of post in Facebook using following code

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Once i share post or link to Facebook then it will take title and description.

But when I share the same post or link to Facebook with other title and image, the title and image do not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your url by passing any auto generated value,

Hope this will work for you.